# ```webAuthSession.presentationContextProvider = self``` ERROR: cannot find self in scope

Tags: swift

I am trying to implement a web authentication service in my app however, when I try to put `webAuthSession.presentationContextProvider = self` , I get an error saying Cannot find 'self' in scope. All the turorials I have followed did the same thing without any errors. I am truly desperate so any help would be appreciated.
Thank you very much in advance!

```
import Foundation
import AuthenticationServices
import CryptoKit

typealias ASPresentationAnchor = UIWindow

class SignInViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject, ASWebAuthenticationPresentationContextProviding {
func presentationAnchor(for session: ASWebAuthenticationSession) -> ASPresentationAnchor {
        return ASPresentationAnchor()
    }
}





public func UrlGenerator() -> URL {
    func randomString(length: Int) -> String {
      let letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
  return String((0..<length).map{ _ in letters.randomElement()! })
}
let code_verifier = randomString(length: 86)
let hashdata = Data(code_verifier.utf8)
let code_challenge_data = SHA256.hash(data: hashdata)
let code_challenge_generated = code_challenge_data.compactMap { String(format: "%02x", $0) }.joined()

let url = "auth.tesla.com/oauth2/v3/authorize"
let client_id = "ownerapi"
let code_challenge = "\(code_challenge_generated)"
let code_challenge_method = "S256"
let redirect_uri = "https://auth.tesla.com/void/callback"
let response_type = "code"
let scope = "openid+email+offline_access"
let state = "\(code_verifier)"

let TeslaLink = "\(url)?client_id=\(client_id)&code_challenge=\(code_challenge)&code_challenge_method=\(code_challenge_method)&redirect_uri=\(redirect_uri)&response_type=\(response_type)&scope=\(scope)&state=\(state)"
    let TeslaLinkURL = URL(string: TeslaLink)!
    return TeslaLinkURL
}



let webAuthSession = ASWebAuthenticationSession.init(
    url: UrlGenerator(),
    callbackURLScheme: "TESRIUM",
    completionHandler: { (callback:URL?, error:Error?) in
})


public func TeslaSignIn() {
    webAuthSession.presentationContextProvider = self
    webAuthSession.prefersEphemeralWebBrowserSession = false
    webAuthSession.start()
}
```

Comment: Can you link to the tutorial?

Comment: This is the tutorial: https://www.swiftdevjournal.com/log-in-to-websites-with-aswebauthenticationsession/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, the reason `self` is not available is because you're referring to it in the global context and `self` has no meaning in the global context. `self` must refer to an object and `self` in the global scope is an environment, not an object.

The reason your specific code doesn't work is because you've separated the instantiation of `webAuthSession` from the work you perform on it. In the tutorial, `webAuthSession = ASWebAuthenticationSession.init...` and `webAuthSession?.presentationContextProvider = self` are in the same scope. Therefore, simply merge them together into the same function. Now, where that function is also matters because if it's a global function you'll have the same problem. You need to place this function into the right object so `self` is referring to what it's supposed to refer to.

```
public func TeslaSignIn() {
    let webAuthSession = ASWebAuthenticationSession.init(
        url: UrlGenerator(),
        callbackURLScheme: "TESRIUM",
        completionHandler: { (callback:URL?, error:Error?) in
    })
    webAuthSession.presentationContextProvider = self
    webAuthSession.prefersEphemeralWebBrowserSession = false
    webAuthSession.start()
}
```

Comment: I have tried your solution, but I am still getting the same error

Comment: @BlazeProg you have to place this function into the right object. You cannot declare it globally. Find out which object this function resides in and move it into there.

Comment: Should I do anything with the class at the beginning of the file?

Comment: @BlazeProg I assume this function is inside the `LoginSession` class, just scanning the tutorial. It appears that everything in that link you provided deals with that class, so I would assume that this function and everything mentioned in that article is inside the `LoginSession` class which in your code is called `SignInViewModel`, so move it all in there. But you should verify this in the tutorial, which I believe to be the case.